# Imagem dentro de div redonda

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tenho um bloco div com altura e largura de 55px e border-radius: 100%; e quero por uma imagem dentro, mas se a imagem for retangular e eu deixo-a com border-radius: 100%; ela fica de forma oval!
Tem como a div sobrepor a imagem e tapar a parte fora do circulo desse jeito :
[image: imagem com exemplo]

Mesmo que a imagem seja meio retangular, sem a destorcer ?
Entendo que a div deve sobrepor a imagem, no finalizando assim : 
[image: resultado final]

Desde já, Obrigado!

Comment: É só por a imagem dentro da `<div>` como `background`. Aí ele vai mostrar a imagem redonda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que as dimensões da imagem sempre será a mesma, tente da seguinte maneira:

```css
.img-arredondada {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-position: -15px -15px;
  height: 195px;
  width: 195px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-arredondada" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyzfI.jpg)"></div>
```

O `border-radius` deixa arredondado.
O `background-position` faz ignorar a faixa superior, começando a imagem onde interessa.
O `height` junto com o `width` fazem ignorar faixa inferior, terminando a imagem no ponto certo.

Comment: Porque o voto contra? Algum motivo?

Answer (score 7):

Definindo o *overflow* da `div` como *hidden* é possível fazer isso sem utilizar a imagem como background.

Caso a imagem não caiba proporcionalmente na `div` defina uma cor de fundo para a imagem não fica cortada

```css
.round {
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    background: black;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="round">
    <img src="http://www.wingspan.co.nz/images/raptor.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Tente isso utilizando a imagem dele: `http://i.stack.imgur.com/AyzfI.jpg`.